# Animating table cell color changes in Keynote

Tags: keynote

Is it possible to animate a table cell color changes in Keynote? If this is not possible, then are any cell-level animations available? I did see a similar question from 2013 here, but I am hoping improvements have been made since then.

Comment: How about animating the transition with "Magic Transition"? I've checked that and cell color animated pretty well.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I am using Keynote 9.2.1 and I do not see Magic Transition, Magic Move, or any other form of magic available :)

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Correction - I do see Magic Move, but this is for transitions between slides. I'm just looking to animate an object on a single slide.

Comment: I don't know how to animate one cell on the same slide. For me only the "Magic Move" works.